# ClientSide caching DropDownList with HUGE amount of data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, gridview

**SCENARIO:** I have a GridView which has DropDownList in each row that gets bound on rowbound event. This data comes from Database and doesn't change very often. (say it changes weekly). As per my understanding the database it hit as many times as there are rows in GridView. One thing that I can do to minimize database hits is to use ViewState or session. BUT, the dropdown data will still be transferred to client side again and again. This is huge data (3MB).
Even I use ajax calls there would still be a lot of data being transferred. 
 It might not be an issue for fast internet connections but for slow internet connection will result in slowdowns. I was wondering if I can save dropdown data on client side and and bind it from there?

I came across an article that explains how I can store data on clientside in  [HTML5 CLIENT SIDE CACHING](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chinnasrihari/html5-and-Asp-Net-client-side-caching-techniques/)

But I would like a solution that works on browsers that dont support HTML5 as well. What would by my best bet and why?

Comment: Why don't you use something like select2 [link] https://select2.github.io/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach of using the HTML5 local storage is the best and the only possible in caching data larger then 100kb on the client side, but it would be hard for you to deserialize, unless you store you object as json string to the local storage, Since local storage or HTML5 is an issue you can always use cookie, but, if it really 3mb (cant imagine the size of that drop-down) it will not be possible since cookie can store MAX~5KB

Comment: Cookie limit is 4KB. Cookies do not fit here because they are meant to store information like user preferences, configuration settings etc and not the actual data itself.

Comment: Cookies are there to store text, cookie has no idea what you store in it user preferences, configuration settings are still text, maybe it will not be used as it typically used but it does not mean that you cant store text other than what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As said, data is more than 3mb  also not changing frequently. Two things i would suggest to do, 
1. Don't store this much amount of data on browser. Use server side Cache object.if possible try to use cache dependency. 
2. Use auto complete dropdown kind of stuff. Always bind top 30( or more ) data to dropdown to reduce load on page. if data is not visible in top 30 then auto complete would help to search appropriate data.

Let me know if this idea helps..